# How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

How do I center the text horizontally and vertically in a `TextView`, so that it appears exactly in the middle of the `TextView` in `Android`?

Comment: set both layout_width and layout_height to fill_parent, then 
set gravity to center. That'll do the trick

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated now so use MATCH_PARENT in  layout_width and layout_height and set gravity of the TextView to center.

Answer (score 3424, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using XML layout.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/**yourtextstring**"
/>
```

You can also use gravity `center_vertical` or `center_horizontal` according to your need.

As @stealthcopter commented, in java: `.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`.

And for Kotlin users, `.gravity = Gravity.CENTER`

Comment: This doesn't work when used with a RelativeLayout where the layout's height & width are set to wrap_content

Comment: @Rob, if the width and height are wrap_content, then technically, the text is already centered.

Comment: If I want to align TextView relative to another view, but it's text centered in itself?

Comment: If you're a minimalist like me you can drop the layout tags.

Comment: This isn't working for me (`android:gravity="center"`). It still shows at far left of screen. :(

Comment: it sounds like your Textviews width and height are set to wrap_content. If this is the case you can set layout_gravity to center

Comment: Not to be confused with `android:layout_gravity="center"`, which does something else.

Comment: In a Relative Layout if you set: 

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
and `android:gravity="center"`
that works for me.

Comment: gravity=center not working. Textview height=34dp and width=100dp.Please help

Comment: Don't forget, there is also `center_veritcal` and `center_horizontal`.

Comment: @ Rob,relative layout provides android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: you can also set manually the height and width to certain value to implement gravity.

Comment: I needed to make sure the height was set to `match_parent` before I could get `gravity="center"` to work vertically in addition to working horizontally. (because if I left it as wrap-content, even if the content was in the corner of the parent, it didn't 'look' like it was centered, even though it technically was, but the height was less than the parent)

Comment: The key is `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center"`. If height is "wrap_content", it won't work.

Comment: That centers the TextView, the question is how to center the text inside the TextView and I believe the answer is:- ```android:textAlignment="center"```

Comment: Technically, the text is already centered if the width and height are `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 489):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

This will do the trick

Comment: The textview has to be match_parent or fill_parent for this to work. If its wrap content, then it will not center.

Comment: @KalelWade: centering text in a textview with wrap_content makes no sense at all.  Maybe you're thinking of centering a textview in a parent view, in which case, you simiply put this line in the parent.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Thus the reason to not use wrap content - it doesn't make sense. But when you're either coping and pasting or just rushing, you may not put two and two together. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: if TextView with width and height equal "wrap_content" is inside LinearLayout with width and height "match_parent"  then you need to set the layout_gravity of Linear_layout.

Comment: @MooingDuck, when height is "wrap_content" and gravity is "center_vertical", it draws in Design (preview) as centered, but in a device it is positioned to a top. So make height "match_parent" and set gravity to "center_vertical" or "center".

Comment: the question is how to center the text inside the TextView and I believe the answer is:- android:textAlignment="center"

Answer (score 315):

You can also set it up dynamically using:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Or just textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Comment: What is the criteria for judgement to decide which way to choose, to write in xml or write in Java file?

Comment: @Kenju if you want it to be easily editable and the value won't change during runtime: XML. If you must change the value realtime (for example, change the alignment when the user presses a button) then you can only do it via Java.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel so, basically xml unless it needs to be modified dynamically ... Now i got it. Thanks for your simple and useful answer !

Answer (score 127):

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

This works when used with a RelativeLayout where the layout's height & width are set to wrap_content.

Comment: This centers the TextView, not the text in it.

Comment: This does NOT work when there is word-wrap in the `TextView`. The text will be full-width and multi-line AND LEFT-justified within the `TextView`. It will appear left-justified on the display. You should use "gravity" as specified in the other answers.

Answer (score 89):

You can also use the combination:

```
android:gravity="left|center"
```

Then, if textview width is more than "fill_parent" the text will still be aligned to left (not centered as with gravity set only to "center").

Answer (score 59):

Apply gravity:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

For vertical:

```
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

In XML:

```
<TextView      
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Hello_World"        
/>
```

Answer (score 46):

There are two ways of doing this.

The first in the XML code. You need to pay attention at the `Gravity` Attribute. You also can find this attribute in the Graphic Editor; it may be easier than the XML EDITOR.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Your Text"
/>
```

For your specific scenario, the values of gravity will be:

```
center_vertical|center_horizontal
```

In the graphical editor you will find all the possible values, even see their results.

Answer (score 41):

If you are using TableLayout make sure to set the gravity of the TableRows to center, too.
Otherwise it will not work. At least it didn't work with me until I set the gravity of the TableRow to center.

For example, like this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">        
    <TextView android:text="@string/chf" android:id="@+id/tv_chf" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"></TextView>        
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Interesting. Have to check if that is valid for LinearLayout (the TableRow parent) as well.

Answer (score 39):

You need to set **TextView Gravity** (Center Horizontal & Center Vertical) like this:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

And dynamically using:

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Code semantics is wrong. Replace `layout_centerhorizontal` and `layout_centervertical` by `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertical` ("H" and "V" to uppercase, otherwise it wont work).

Comment: layout_* tells the View's parent where it wants to be. Without layout_* tells the View how to place its components

Answer (score 34):

In my opinion,

```
android:gravity="center"
```

is better than,

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

which is better than,

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

at least for formatting text.

Answer (score 33):

For Linear Layout:
In XML use something like this

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Your Text goes here"
/>
```

To do this at run time use something like this in your activity

```
TextView textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texView1);
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

For Relative Layout: in XML use some thing like this

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Your Text goes here"
/>
```

To do this at run time use something like this in your activity

```
TextView textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView1.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 25):

Use in the XML file.

**Layout file**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/stringtext"/>
```

or:

**Use this inside the Java class**

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texviewid);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 22):

Use this  for relative layout

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

and for other layout

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 20):

If the `TextView's` height and width are `wrap content` then the text within the `TextView` always be centered. But if the `TextView's` width is `match_parent` and height is `match_parent` or `wrap_content` then you have to write the below code:

For **RelativeLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:text="Hello World" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For **LinearLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

While using gravity works for TextView, there's an alternate method implemented in API level 17 -

```
textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

Don't know the difference, but it works too. However only for API level 17 or higher.

Comment: The difference is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196444/text-layout-alignment-in-android-textalignment-gravity

Comment: This will truly center the text in the TextView. If you just use gravity, there's a bit of trailing padding depending on what the text is.... If you have a little circle badge with text in the center, for instance, you can see a very obvious difference.

Answer (score 14):

In `RelativeLayout`, it will be nice with it.

And another `Button` and anything else you can add.

The following works nicely for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff314859"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your text here"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

        ...other button or anything else...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `android:textAlignment="center"`

[image]

```
       <TextView
        android:text="HOW WAS\nYOUR\nDAY?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
         />
```

Comment: textAlignment="center"  won't do the job until the TextView has dimensions to match_parent

Comment: @SAurabh above example is working without any issues.

Comment: is it working without gravity to parent or layout gravity in itself?
It won't
Text alignment will align the text within its view bounds so until the textView takes match_parent in this case it it won't seem like this without gravity in its parent layout or layout_gravity in itself

Answer (score 11):

You can just set the `gravity` of your textview into `CENTER`.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way (which is surprisingly only mentioned in comments, hence why I am posting as an answer) is:

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
```

Answer (score 11):

TextView gravity works as per your parent layout.

**LinearLayout**:

If you use LinearLayout then you will find two gravity attribute
android:gravity & android:layout_gravity

android:gravity : represent layout potion of internal text of TextView while
android:layout_gravity : represent TextView position in parent view.

[image]

If you want to set text horizontally & vertically center then use below code this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**RelativeLayout**:

Using RelativeLayout you can use below property in TextView

android:gravity="center" for text center in TextView.

android:gravity="center_horizontal" inner text if you want horizontally centered.

android:gravity="center_vertical" inner text if you want vertically centered.

android:layout_centerInParent="true" if you want TextView in center position of parent view.
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" if you want TextView in horizontally center of parent view.
android:layout_centerVertical="true" if you want TextView in vertically center of parent view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Btw, any reason you rollbacked to the previous revision? The revision that you reverted is a good practice so that as what the editor has mentioned can help text editors with encoding.

Comment: Thank you for `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to center text on a TableRow in a TableLayout, here is how I achieved this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/rowName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dip" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblSomeLabel"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="100"
              android:text="Your Text Here" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Relative Layout:

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stringname"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

If you are using LinearLayout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stringname"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this way,it will work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
  
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is my answer that I had used in my app. It shows text in center of the screen.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSubject"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/subject"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 9):

The TextView's height and width are wrap content then the text within the textview always be centered, then make center in its parent layout by using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello.."/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For LinearLayout also the code is same :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello.."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and pro-grammatically parent is RelativeLayout java code this at run time use something like this in your activity

```
TextView textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView1.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, we can do better by excluding fontPadding.

```xml
<TextView
  android layout_height="wrap_content"
  android layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:includeFontPadding="false"
  android:textAlignment="center"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, `android:includeFontPadding="false"` removes small paddings around the text.

Answer (score 8):

As many answers suggest above works fine.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

If you want to center it just vertically:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

or just horizontally:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 8):

We can achieve this with these multiple ways:-

> XML method 01

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@strings/text"
/>
```

> XML method 02

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@strings/text"
/>
```

> XML method 03

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@strings/text"
/>
```

> XML method 04

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@strings/text"
/>
```

> Java method 01

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

> Java method 02

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

> Java method 03

```
textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply, in your XML file, set the textview gravity to center:

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 7):

`android:gravity="center_horizontal"` for align text Center horizontally.
`android:gravity="center_vertical"` for align text Center vertically.
`android:gravity="center"` for align text Center both vertically and horizontally.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this to get text centered

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: center text]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/failresults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you have textview inside linearlayout, you need set them both gravity to center

Answer (score 4):

I don't think, You really need to do that just define your TextView in layout file like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="width"
    android:layout_height="height">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourid"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

just add this in your xml.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned in other answers, you can set gravity in xml with:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and in java code :

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
```

in kotlin code :

```
textview.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

but if you are doing this in kotlin compose, you can center gravity using :

```
textAlign = TextAlign.Center
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the gravity attribute in the layout file as
`android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 3):

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are making your text view width and height to wrap content then you have to manage it's position via layout gravity according to the parent supported attributes. Else you can do.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

For **kotlin**:

If you want to center your `TextView` from code:

```
textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

If you want to `horizontally` center:

```
textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
```

Or, `vertically` center:

```
textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
```

Answer (score 3):

For the layout of text, it is better to use

android:textAlignment="center"

and for the other layout of objects etc, it's good to use

android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
android:id="+@id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this way?

```
<TextView
android:id="+@id/txtVw"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the below code in xml it worked for me you can change the orientation it will be in the centre

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="centre me"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:gravity="center"` to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView  
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:gravity="center"
android:text="In the center"/>
```

Above is to set it using .xml file.

but I prefer java version because you can also disable it in code while in running condition if necessary. Following is java code.

```
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

this will do the trick

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

To show text in the center like:

```
------------------>text<-------------------
```

Use these styles:

```html
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_contect" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
/>

android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `RelativeLayout`, try using this property  inside your `TextView` tag :

```
android:layout_centerInParent= true
```

Comment: The "true" should be in quotes

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added xml snippet to make a textview center alligned in both Linear and Relative Layout.

**In Linear Layout**

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Text In Center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

**In Relative Layout**

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Text In Center"
android:layout_centerInParent= true/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Let's say Full Textview in screen**

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

**Let's say Textview(not full) in Relative layout**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_centerInParent=true
    />
```

**Let's say Textview(not full) in Linear_layout**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="centre"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Via .`xml` file gravity can be set to center as follows

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="In the center"
/>
```

Via java following is the way you can solve your particular issue

```
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the gravity to center vertical and textalignment to center.

```
<TextView
     android:text="@string/yourText"
     android layout_height="wrap_content"
     android layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

This line in xml would help you to center the `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the Gravity like this:

```
(textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Using LinearLayout if you are using **textview height and width match_parent** You can set the gravity text to center and **text alignment to center text horizontal** if you are using textview height and width wrap_content then add gravity center attribute in your LinearLayout.

**XML Code**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Welcome to Android" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java code**

> You can programatically do like this:-

```
(textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Honorable Mention for the Belated GUI**

I wanted to add some value to this already fantastic thread. And finally after 11 years we now have a way to drag and drop the TextView from the toolbox and select gravity through a GUI Properties box. AND, thankfully the GUI  combines the properties concisely as "center_vertical|center_horizontal".

[image]

```
    <TextView
    android:text="This is my sample text."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35.7dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24.7dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the location of the layout, image or textview comes under the topic of alignment. so if you want to put your image src in middle vertically, you should use the code below written

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

and for center Horizontally

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

or else, I think we can also use gravity to put every element in mid of parent layout like `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Tours"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

And for those wondering how to center it vertically in its TextView element while keeping it on the left (horizontally) :

```
android:gravity="center"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
There are 2 ways to do this :

1. From Xml
     use :  
        <TextView
         .........
        android:gravity="center"/>

2. From Java class
    use : 

     [textview].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center a Text View using android:gravity="center"

The code goes as follows

```
    <TextView
     android:text="@string/yourText"
     android layout_height="wrap_content"
     android layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If that TextView doesn't have the height / width attributes set to `wrap_content`, just use `android:gravity="center"`. But some people complain that using that does not work. That's because their layout doesn't have the same gravity. You can set

`android:layout_gravity="center"` **IN THE TEXTVIEW** (this will apply only to the TextView)

or

`android:gravity="center"` **IN THE PARENT LAYOUT** (this will apply to all the views inside it)

Answer (score 0):

In ConstraintLayout for any view:

(When you are using a constraint layout, set height & width to 0, and let the constraint to manage view bounds.)

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to center a view or its content e.g. TextView or Button
>   horizontally and vertically? layout_gravity can be used to position a
>   view in the center of its parent. While gravity attribute is used to
>   position view’s content e.g. “text” in the center of the view.

**( 1 ) Center TextView Horizontally**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#333"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**( 2 ) Center TextView Vertically**

> android:layout_gravity=”center_vertical” dose not work!!

To center TextView vertically, you need to make a trick. Place TextView inside a RelativeLayout then set the TextView attribute android:layout_centerInParent=”true”
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#333"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**( 3 ) Center Text Horizontally**

> android:gravity=”center_horizontal"

[image]

**( 4 ) Center Text Horizontally & Vertically**

> android:gravity=”center” this will center the text horizontally and
>   vertically

[image]

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:text="Hello World!"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:background="#333"
>     android:textColor="#fff"
>     />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gravity Property in the TextView to center the Text Vertically and Horizontally.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:gravity="center" to parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello world"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

```
<TextView  
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="**Your String Value**" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change`android:gravity` for this.

`android:gravity="center"` or

if you want to center horizontal or vertical

`android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

`android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically do this in java with: textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Textview width and height should be match_parent and add android:gravity="center" in your textview attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one single TextView into your XML file then you can make the parent view gravity as the centre.
This will make your child element in the centre of the screen and then you can make your child view as a wrap for both height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Font padding can also affect the position of text you can remove it by adding includefontpadding=false

```
<TextView
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here in case it saves someone the 2 hours it took me to find :

If your text is too big in a given dimension, it won't attempt to center it in that dimension. That makes sense, but a `TextView` has 'font padding' by default. So it's possible to set a text size such that the height looks like it fits comfortably inside your text view, but in fact it is 'too big' because it encroaches on the font padding. In this situation, the text will NOT be vertically centered, the request will be ignored. The solution is simple - just remove this annoying font padding with:

`android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Then it centers vertically as expected.