# How to set the text in the center of text view

Tags: android, textview, center, gravity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I center text horizontally and vertical in a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

I want to set the text in the center of textview (vertical and horizontal) . it is horizontally centered by vertical it has more space in the top of the  text.

xml layout :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQuantity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="HELLO I AM ANDROID DEVELOPER"
/>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` instead of `android:gravity="center|center_vertical"`.

This will center it both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: If you down vote, it is of great assistance to post a reason why you down voted.