# Android Text Alignment - Pixel Perfect

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

In the screenshot below, I am attempting to get the text in the blue box to be aligned in the centre. It is to low down and needs to be lifted a pixel or two. I have been playing with the padding but it does not seem to have any effect.

[image]

The layout XML is here :

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName" 
        android:layout_width="60dp" 
        android:layout_height="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/rectanglesegment" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" 
        android:text="XXX" android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Any suggestions?

After feedback from @Snicolas I now have the following :

[image]

With this layout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvName" 
android:layout_width="60dp" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectanglesegment" 
android:gravity="center"
android:text="abv" android:textSize="16sp" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Comment: paddingTop -2 didn't work ?

Comment: you could also try with android:capitalize = true.

Comment: This thread is for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android

Comment: @Snicolas It is already using `android:gravity="center"`...

Comment: What did you try in the edit, it's not clear ? And did you see I suggested a negative top padding ?

Comment: @Snicola The paddingTop -2 (with the negative) did not seem to have any effect at all. The link to the stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/… pointed me in the right direction by having 

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

and then that seemed to let the existing 

android:gravity="center"

work.

Comment: So you can accept your own answer and accept it. That's fine and will be more usefull for other people with same question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the extra room on top is just [font padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aincludeFontPadding)(for accents, etc). Try this:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about playing with [`android:lineSpacingExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alineSpacingExtra) or [`android:lineSpacingMultiplier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alineSpacingMultiplier)? These XML attributes call [`setLineSpacing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing%28float,%20float%29).

> `public void setLineSpacing (float add, float mult)`
>
> Sets line spacing for this TextView. Each line will have its height
>   multiplied by `mult` and have `add` added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the background image - rectanglesegment. It is probably 9 patch image and needs adjustment.