# Text/Layout Alignment in Android (textAlignment, gravity)

Tags: android, mobile, layout, text-alignment, layout-gravity

What's the difference between `android:textAlignment` and `android:gravity`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

All I can see is that the textAlignment is a member of the View Class and the gravity is the member of TextView class. So for the TextView and its subclasses you can use the gravity while you can use the textAlignment for all Views.

As the TextView and its subclasses need some more text-aligning features, so you can see there are more options in gravity where in textAlignment there are only basic options. Although it is only my guess because I have not found any clear documentation about the difference.

You can see these two links of documentation: [textAlignment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment) and [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity).

Comment: watch out when using other people's widgets, it seems gravity does not override `textAlignment` so for instance you need to set `textAlignment` as opposed to `gravity` when overriding `Snackbar` default set up. ie. 
```val textView = sb.view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)
                        textView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER```

Answer (score 17):

With API 15, `android:textAlignment` may not have the desired result. The snippet below attempts to centre the first `TextView` object using `android:textAlignment="center"`. The second uses `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`. The `textAlignment` has no effect whereas the gravity works fine. With API 17+, `textAlignment` centres the text as expected.

To be certain that your text is aligned correctly with all releases, I'd go with gravity.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Fri"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="29"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Resulting layout in API 15:
[image: Resulting layout in API 15]

Resulting layout in API 17+:
[image: Resulting layout in API 17+]

Comment: `android:textAlignment` is only available for API 17+, that is why there is no effect on lower versions.

Answer (score 15):

Another point not explicitly mentioned:

If your application has RTL support disabled with e.g. `android:supportsRtl="false"` in manifest `application` tag, then `View` `textAlignment` does not work for text positioning while `TextView` `gravity` works.

Yet another reason to prefer `gravity`.

Comment: took me several hours when suddenly text alignment in my layout not working as expected

Answer (score 7):

As far as I've seen textAlignment seems to be mostly unused.
By it's description, it should do just right or left alignment.
Gravity seems to be an improved textAlignment.