# Textview Gravity not working properly in android

Tags: java, android, layout-gravity

What's wrong with my code, I'm trying to display my TextView named  `"invalid"`, in different locations (left,right,center), but the gravity (left,right,center) won't work! [image]

**My text.xml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etext"
        android:hint="@string/comment"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button" 
            android:layout_weight="25"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="ToggleButton" 
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invalid"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My TextPlay.java is**

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity {
    Button button;
    ToggleButton tbutton;
    TextView tview;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext);
        tbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tbutton.isChecked()) {
                    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String input = et.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(input);
                if (input.contentEquals("left")) {
                    tview.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                } else if (input.contentEquals("right")) {
                    System.out.println("inside right");
                    tview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else if (input.contentEquals("right")) {
                    tview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: remove android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center" from your layout for @+id/textView1 and try...

Comment: Change the `TextView`'s width to `match_parent` or use `android:layout_gravity` in stead.

Comment: Take a look at this questions as well: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: Why should you want to use tabs in code they are a waste of code size...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You set this text view a width of "**wrap_content**"  it means,  what ever the text is, the view take the size of the text.

and in the `LinearLayout` , the default gravity (used here) is '**center**'

you should try this :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"   <= change this
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/invalid"
android:gravity="center"   <= then this gravity will be taken into account
/>
```

Answer (score 30):

99% of the time, `not working properly` == `not used properly`.

You are mistaking `gravity` and `layout_gravity`.

`gravity` is the way the text will align itself **in the `TextView`**. The `TextView` being in `wrap_content` this does nothing, as the `TextView` is exactly the size of the text.

`layout_gravity` is the way the `TextView` will align itself in its parent, in your case in the vertical `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Harmen `gravity` is an attribute defined only for `TextView`.

Answer (score 3):

You have given your TextView width wrap_content, and that is the problem, Check below code and replace it to your code.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtInvalid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/invalid"
android:gravity="center"   
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason why gravity does not work properly can be if you have `gravity` and  `textAlignment`

If you put it like this

```
    <TextView                                                                     
        android:id="@+id/textView1"                      
        android:layout_width="200dp"                                              
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"                                
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Android studio editor will give this warning:

`Inconsistent alignment specification between textAlignment and gravity attributes: was center|center_horizontal, expected start (Incompatible direction here)`

But if you add textAlignment inside the styles then it doesn't complain.

This can be the issue why your gravity value will not work

```
    <TextView                                                                     
        android:id="@+id/textView2"                                          
        style="@style/Widget.App.TextView.Label.Default"                          
        android:layout_width="200dp"                                              
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
```

Check this answer for the difference between them:

[Text/Layout Alignment in Android (textAlignment, gravity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196444/text-layout-alignment-in-android-textalignment-gravity)

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for textView1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have something like that hanging around

```
app:layout_box="left|top"
```