# set TextView's gravity programmatically in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, layout-gravity

I am programmatically change the Gravity and background of TextView in ConstrainLayout the background color change correctly but the gravity don't change how to solve this problem please

```
 if(currentUserId.equals(model.getUserId())){
                    holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_sender_bubbles);
                    holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                }else
                {
                    holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_resiver_bubbles);
                    holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                }
```

the xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_message_profile"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message_name"
        android:text="user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image_message_profile"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025301/textview-gravity-not-working-properly-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gravity` has no effect if `TextView` has width equal to `wrap_content`.

See also:
[Textview Gravity not working properly in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025301/textview-gravity-not-working-properly-in-android)