# TextView will not center its content

Tags: android

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/list_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        />
```

Is the first element in a RelativeLayout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
```

But the text in the TextView will not center. I cannot understand why as all gravities and the `textAlignment` property are set to "center".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `android:gravity="center"` instead for the `TextView`

Comment: In case anyone is using **custom fonts**, refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648299/14784590

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to your textView

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was using android:layout_gravity I see now. What's the difference?

Comment: android:gravity applies graivity to the content of the view, while
android:layout_gravity applies gravity to the view itself inside its parent.

Comment: I see, so android:gravity on the parent is equivalent to android:layout_gravity on the child then, in terms of the effect it has on the child?

Comment: Details on the difference between `android:textAlignment` and `android:gravity`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197308/2848676

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/list_title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        />
```

Comment: Here we care about answers with good explanations, not just code. Only post an answer if it really solves the question and you can explain how. To improve your future answers, take a look the the guide [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if your textview is inside a constraintLayout then set its width to 0dp and then apply these constraints

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
android:textAlignment="center"
```