# TextView with custom font isn't centered vertically

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I need to use a custom font (VAG Rounded, probably not relevant) but the font changes how my TextViews react.

In the image below, you can see the two textviews with a black background. The left one use the custom font, the right one the default system font (Roboto ?). Both of them have the same xml properties and size, but the padding is not the same and more important, the left one isn't centered vartically !

[image]

How can I make the TextView draw its content well centered ?

Comment: `centered` ... do you mean **vertically**?

Comment: better try another font, if that works? Plus also use center_horizontally or vertically as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not change the font, and I wasn't going to edit each character using an editor (I don't even know what I should have done to fix it).

Si I ended up measure the difference with the default font and I added `0.15f * fontSize` in the padding top...

Answer (score 15):

You can try to remove your customs font padding from your text style (styles.xml):

```
<item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
```

If this still doesn't work, i would set a general `padding` in your styles xml.

Comment: this works great, for some fonts you still have to set paddings, but this removes artifact paddings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and then also `android:gravity="center"`

then if you post also your source code we can give you more information