# TextView Not centered in app but centered in match_constraint

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created a simple activity design using ConstraintLayout.
Whenever I try to center a textView, it does it correctly in the blueprints but never does it in the actual app. Not sure if i am doing something wrong or I'm losing my mind.

Here is the image[image]

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_green"
tools:context="nz.co.listcosolutions.StartActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="163dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="95dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/baby_plant" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="@color/background_green"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Welcome to My App"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Im also using the latest version of ConstraintLayout

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Your `TextView` need `android:gravity="center"` in his properties. (if you refer about centering the text inside)

Comment: Yeah thats fixed the text. Shouldn't textAlignment do the exact same? Especially because its showing correctly in the blueprints

Comment: No it isn't, `textAlignment` it's practically useless

Comment: Ah strange. I thought they were always basically the same. Whenever I've used the 'textAllignment' tag its worked perfectly for me. Please put your answer as a proper answer to I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

> `android:gravity="center"`

to the `TextView`.
This is the only certain way to center the text inside a `TextView` object or one of its subclasses.

The `android:textAlignment` is not working in all the cases and as reported by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491997/2910520) that it has problems in lower API levels.