# TextView with Background and centered text

Tags: android, background, textview

I want to create a TextView which has a custom background.
In particular I would like to have a Text view which looks like [this](http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/929604/9119065/0/1243046467/Graphic_LCD_Display.jpg).
I know that i can set a background to a TextView with `android:background="@drawable/displaybackground` but how can i align the text in this textview. The text should be displayed in the center of the Textview, like in the image above.

kind regards

Comment: Lack of research. Not a real problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center text horizontally and vertical in a TextView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `center` for the `gravity` property in the TextView (not the `layout_gravity`).

Answer (score 6):

Here you are.
You just have to find the background, that you like.

```
<Textview
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" //center the text horizontally, and vertically
    android:text="You place your text here..." // Text inside the TextView
    android:background="background Here"/> // Background (drawable or color)
```

Answer (score 0):

find below link for that:

[How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

Good Luck :)