# android.widget.TextView.setTextAlignment(): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, textview, adt, android-xml

## Situation:

I have a `TextView` that have the property

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

I am generating another `TextView` dinamically, based on my `TextView` from XML Layout, using a clone, cloning all the basic properties to work the way above.

## Problem:

To do this i need to use this method:

```
this.myTextView.setMyTextViewProperty(MyTextView.getMyTextViewProperty());
```

for example:

```
this.MyTextView.setText(MyTextView.getText());
```

> Note that `this.MyTextView`is a local variable and `MyTextView` is a private var declared on the top of the file, under class name.

I do this on all the properties of the `TextView` but when i hit the following line of code from the `TextAlignment` property...:

```
this.myTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

I tried to set it to a Custom Aligment instead of getting from my XML `TextView` It gives me an error:

```
11-20 15:27:04.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 15:27:04.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9185): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setTextAlignment
```

But i see on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> that the method exists, so i cant understand what is happening.

A second try was, to set my `TextView` property to the property that comes from my `TextView`:

```
this.myTextView.setTextAlignment(MyTextView.getTextAlignment());
```

With no success, too.

### **Obs: i do not want a Android XML Layout solution, i want a solution on code, because i generate the `TextView` dinamically on the `Activity`**

## **I'm using API Level 15**

Any help?

Comment: what is the api level you are testing on?

Comment: My device have API Level 15(Android 4.0.3)

Comment: It is available in api levle 17. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextAlignment(int) and that's why the error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The setTextAlignment method was added in API level 17. Maybe your compiler in the IDE is above 17 and the device/emulator which you are testing is less than that. Here the [link to setTextAlignment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextAlignment(int)).

Added from the comments:

For API level 15 and below, you want [setGravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432037/9636).

Comment: Ok, this was helpful, but what i can do to align my `TextView` assuming that i use a API Level 15 Device?

Comment: @PauloRoberto looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android

Comment: @Raghunandan this dont solve my problem because i need to set it programatically, and i have the same error if i try to set/get the `Gravity` of my `TextView`

Comment: @PauloRoberto how did you try setting the gravity programatically. show the code.

Comment: i do not remember exactly, can you show me how to do that, so i will try again

Comment: @Raghunandan i edited my whole question and voted to be re-opened, you can see it later if you want, and your comment is correct, all the problem was API Level.