# How to change the floating label position of TextInputLayout centre horizontal

Tags: android, android-studio

I want the floating label position to be centre align. I searched a lot but didn't get any solution.

Please help me.

Comment: did you try .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) or .getLayoutParams().gravity = Gravity.CENTER ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-on-android)

Comment: it is not duplicate question

Comment: you can not customize the label position TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email"
             android:gravity="center"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: this is the correct solution to center the floating label

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried setting textAlignment and gravity properties...give them a try

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Set the align on the gravity, on android:gravity="center_horizontal". So it could be:

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="your hint" />
```

Hope this helps.