# How to move text in the textview?

Tags: android, textview

I want to move text in the textview a little bit higher. How I can do that? 
My textview:

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="45dp" 
       android:layout_height="45dp" 
     **android:id="@+id/tv_number"** 
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
       android:background="@drawable/oval" 
       android:textIsSelectable="false" 
       android:textStyle="normal|bold" 
       android:textSize="40sp" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
       android:text="1" 
       android:textColor="#ffffff" 
       tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" 
       android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

Comment: Can you explain yourself ? what do you mean with higher

Comment: Use gravity to move the text, Make sure TextView have enough width. And you are already using textSize, can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Also try to add full layout so we can help you out @Олег Медведев

Comment: Please explain what you want clearly

Comment: add dp to margin_bottom or padding_bottom, if this doesnt work, try to remove the " android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" "

Answer (score 3):

You can set the padding bottom or top. If you set the padding bottom, your Text is placed higher and if you set a padding top your Text will be placed lower.
Try:
`android:paddingBottom="5dp"`

Answer (score 0):

For the text inside Textview, you need to set "android:gravity" which makes the content of Your TextView aligned . You have used "android:layout_gravity" which makes alignment of TextView respected to its Parent Layout.

So as to change the vertical alignment of text inside textview, for example you can use, 
android:gravity="center|right"

If you want to exactly center your text, this might be helpful 
[How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-on-android)