# set some text of a string at the center of a TextView

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I want to fix some text of string in the center. How can I do that? 
For example, take a look on this photo

[image: Heading at the center]

I have a string like that. Now I want some words (Heading) of my string to be shown in a `TextView` at the center horizontally but others word will remain as usual. How can I do that?

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work for various dimension's devices.

```
          String string= "                 SYRIA
\n\nSyria oh Syria why do you bleed?
        \nBrother fights brother without thought or need
    \nRuled by a tyrant for so many years
    \nAnd now the split blood is washed away by tears\n"
```

Comment: You can take two different textview and set first textview gravity to center

Comment: If this is the only case then you can use Two `TextView` for it . If this can multiple times like a paragraph then you should go with `HTML` text . Or you can directly use HTML for this scenario too .

Comment: You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-on-android) for making text align center in a textview.

Comment: I have long paragraph actually and some text of the paragraph needs to be aligned center only. Multiple TextView makes the whole purpose more complicated in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wither use 2 different Textviews or If there is single textview, you can use HTML or Spannable String for that. Spannable can be used as follows:

```
TextView resultView = new TextView(this);
final String SyriaText = "Syria";
final String OtherText = "Other Text";
final String result = SyriaText + "  " + OtherText;
final SpannableString finalResult = new SpannableString(result);
finalResult.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, SyriaText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
resultView.setText(finalResult);
```

Also you can style it with Spannable. You can learn more from : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.fromHtml`.Using this you only need single `textview`. Just do this, it should work perfectly

```
 your_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h><center><b><u>SYRIA</u></b></center></h>\n" +
            "    <p>Syria oh Syria why do you bleed?</p> </br>\n" +
            "    <p>Brother fights brother without thought or need</p> </br>\n" +
            "    <p>Ruled by a tyrant for so many years</p> </br>\n" +
            "    <p>And now the split blood is washed away by tears</p> </br>"));
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but  the heading didn't take position at the center.

Comment: it will take the center position, iam attaching a screenshot of the result in my answer

Comment: Please check my result.  would you please share your xml code for textview?  

https://prnt.sc/iri6vn 

It seems to me from your pic that you have aligned the whole TextView as center. So, rest of the text gets also aligned center. But I need only heading at the center.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="seria"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Syria oh Syria why do you bleed?
        \nBrother fights brother without thought or need
    \nRuled by a tyrant for so many years
    \nAnd now the spilt blood is washed away by tears"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```