# QML centralize RowLayout in parent vertically and horizontally not working

Tags: qt, qml

newbee here on QML. I am trying to do something very basic but I can't get it to work properly.

Basically I want to centralize a RowLayout inside a parent rectangle, but the anchors are only working vertically.

What I want is this:

[image]

but this is what I am getting:

[image]

the code:

```
Rectangle
{
    height: implicitHeight
    width: implicitWidth
    color : "cornflowerblue"

    Text {
        text: "C"
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 12
        color: "black"
    }

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }

    }

}
```

I looked into this thread and somewhat helped, but I still don't get the proper horizontal alignment.

Following the suggestion of the comments, I used anchors.centerIn: parent

However now the spacing between rectangles was squashed. Is there an easy way to space the rectangles without adding extra items in between them?

[image]

[How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview)

Comment: For your `RowLayout`, perhaps try using `anchors.centerIn: parent` rather than `anchors.fill: parent`. I'm not sure offhand if the children will layout as expected, but it may achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: that helped but how do I increase the space in between the rectangles? See my edits

Comment: Use `RowLayout`'s `spacing` property to set the spacing between `Items` in the layout: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html#spacing-prop

Comment: worked well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

solution, thanks to dabbler

```
RowLayout
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 20

    Rectangle {
        width: 60
        height: 100
        color: "red"
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 2
        radius: 10
    }
```

etc...